# Typescript type alias empty array bracket

Tags: typescript

I've been going through the typescript documentation for quite some time and I can't seem to find any examples regarding the below example for a type alias. I'm trying to understand what the purpose of the empty array is after the closing object brace.

Thanks!

```
type PostsProps = {
  posts: {
    tags?: {
      name: string
      slug: string
    }[] // what is the purpose of this empty array
  }[] // what is the purpose of this empty array
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an empty array to define an array type.

The empty array in the example code above basically defines the type of `posts` as an array of object(s) with a property of `tags` nested as another array of object(s) where there's `name` and `slug` properties which are both `strings`.

A simpler example, I could define a type for an array of strings like this

```js
let color: string[];

color = ['red', 'green', 'more colors']; // This is ok

color = ['red', 'green', 5]; // This would flag
```

Comment: It might be useful to point out that a type like `Foo[]` is shorthand for `Array<Foo>`, and the only time `[]` is interpreted as an "empty array" is when it stands on its own, as the empty [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) type.

Comment: Thanks. That is what I figured but wasn't sure. I usually would have factored out Tags and Posts into their own type alias or interface and explicitly declared the array type inside the type alias.

Answer (score 0):

`[]` is special shorthand syntax for the `Array` type. So for example, `string[]` and `Array<string>` are equivalent.

A [common code style](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/array-type.md#array-simple) is to use the short version for simple array types like `number[]`, `string[]` or `any[]` while using `Array` for more complex types like `Array<Record<string, string>>`. However, as far as I know, TypeScript always displays the short syntax (in this case `Record<string, string>[]`) when you hover over the type.